# How do I create an array relationship in Hasura?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I'm working with Hasura and using the Postgres database. I'm unable to get my column of `entries` from table `faqTopic` to link to my row from table `faqEntries`. My goal is ultimately to create a nested data structure that looks something like the following:

```
{
    "data": {
        "faq_topic": {
            "id": "faq-topics",
            "title": {
                "id": "faq-topics-title",
                "content": "All FAQs",
                "font_weight": 700,
                "is_href": false,
                "href": null,
                "href_target": null,
                "icon": null,
                "is_expandable": false,
                "character_limit": 96
            },
            "entries": [
                {
                    "id": "faq-topics-entries-0",
                    "title": {
                        "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-title",
                        "content": "Popular Questions",
                        "font_weight": 700,
                        "is_href": false,
                        "href": null,
                        "href_target": null,
                        "icon": null,
                        "is_expandable": false,
                        "character_limit": 96
                    },
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-0",
                            "title": {
                                "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-0-question",
                                "content": "I don’t have my ID card. How do I show my dentist that I have dental coverage?",
                                "font_weight": 700,
                                "is_href": false,
                                "link_type": null,
                                "href_target": null,
                                "icon": null,
                                "is_expandable": false,
                                "character_limit": null
                            },
                            "entries": [
                                {
                                    "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-0-entries-0",
                                    "title": {
                                        "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-0-answer",
                                        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit am molestie sem a ullamcorper pulvinar. Phasellus tempor tortor orci, ut molestie orci aliquet sit amet am interdum nisi augue, ac imperdiet neque ornare a. Quisque nec nunc ultricies, euismod magna at, fermentum ante. Sed dui ex, interdum vel molestie eget, vulputate et quam. am tortor quam, porta id massa ac, tincidunt efficitur nibh. Donec eleifend tortor enim, vitae gravida lorem consectetur ac.",
                                        "font_weight": 400,
                                        "is_href": false,
                                        "link_type": null,
                                        "href_target": null,
                                        "icon": null,
                                        "is_expandable": true,
                                        "character_limit": 250
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-1",
                            "title": {
                                "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-1-question",
                                "content": "I'm enrolled in more than one plan. How does coverage work with two plans?",
                                "font_weight": 700,
                                "is_href": false,
                                "link_type": null,
                                "href_target": null,
                                "icon": null,
                                "is_expandable": false,
                                "character_limit": null
                            },
                            "entries": [
                                {
                                    "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-1-entries-0",
                                    "title": {
                                        "id": "faq-topics-entries-0-entries-1-answer",
                                        "content": "Aenean ultrices faucibus ante, at viverra mi porta eget. Donec varius mi vel facilisis tincidunt. Sed a condimentum ex. Pellentesque congue molestie libero eget suscipit. Sed sed nisi nec felis faucibus gravida. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum faucibus arcu justo, tristique tempor dolor lobortis in. a fringilla nisi ac enim vehicula, ut placerat quam tempus. Curabitur ullamcorper finibus diam, a aliquam urna malesuada venenatis. Duis in massa arcu. a eu turpis eros. Aliquam ac vestibulum nisi, lacinia pulvinar ipsum. Pellentesque vel egestas nisi.",
                                        "font_weight": 400,
                                        "is_href": false,
                                        "link_type": null,
                                        "href_target": null,
                                        "icon": null,
                                        "is_expandable": true,
                                        "character_limit": 250
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                ...
                }
```

So far I'm only able to return

```
{
  "data": {
    "faq_topic": {
      "id": "faq-topics",
      "title": {
        "character_limit": 96,
        "content": "All FAQs",
        "font_weight": 700,
        "href": null,
        "href_target": null,
        "icon": null,
        "id": "faq-topics-title",
        "is_expandable": false,
        "is_href": false
      },
      "entries": null
    }
  }
}
```

In `faqTopic` I've created an object relationship with `faqEntries`. I've also created a foreign key entries -> faqEntries.id

In `faqEntries` I have an array relationship called faqTopicsEntries where I link to faqTopic.entries -> faqEntries.id. The row has data in it yet in my faqTopic table the columns return null.

How can I link my tables so I can write a query that returns the array of entries?

I'm new to Postgres and GraphQL. If more details are necessary feel free to ask.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How would you recommend doing it?

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm doing, but the end result needs to look like that JSON object.

Comment: Can you post here the query you are using to call the faqTopic with the entries? Also, would be good to see a bit of the data structure, such as the SQL migration generated when you created both tables and/or the part in table.yml that shows both tables.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what columns the `faqEntries` table has. Ideally you would like the foreign key relationship the other way around as well, e.g., `faqEnrties.faq_topic_id`-> `faqTopic.id`